# Sort a dictionary with custom sorting function

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, sorting, dictionary

I have some JSON data I read from a file using `json.load(data_file)`

```
 {
  "unused_account":{
    "logins": 0,
    "date_added": 150
  },
  "unused_account2":{
    "logins": 0,
    "date_added": 100
  },
  "power_user_2": {
    "logins": 500,
    "date_added": 400,
    "date_used": 500
  },
  "power_user": {
    "logins": 500,
    "date_added": 300,
    "date_used": 400
  },
  "regular_user": {
    "logins": 20,
    "date_added": 200,
    "date_used": 300
  }
}
```

I want to sort the entries in a specific order. I have found lots of examples to sort by key or one single value. But I would like to sort the values by these rules:

1. groupby logins descending, but users with 0 logins first
2. sort users with 0 logins by date_added
3. sort users with at least 1 login by date_used

Ideally I would write my own compare function like this:

```
def compare(elem1, elem2):
    """Return >0 if elem2 is greater than elem1
        <0 if elem2 is lesser than elem1
        0 if they are equal"""
    #rule 1 group by logins
    if elem1['logins'] != elem2['logins']:
        if elem1['logins'] == 0:
            return -1
        if elem2['logins'] == 0:
            return 1
        return elem2['logins'] - elem1['logins']
    # rule 2 sort on date_added
    if elem1['logins'] == 0 and elem2['logins'] == 0:
        return elem2['date_added'] - elem1['date_added']
    #rule 3 sort on date_used
    if elem1['logins'] == elem2['logins'] and elem1['loigns'] > 0:
        return elem2['date_used'] - elem1['date_used']
    return 0  # default
```

I don't know where and how to plugin my sorting function.

Comment: Can you give us an expected output of your sort? so you want 0 logins first (sorted by date added in what direction? Then the rest with logins by date used, again, what direction?

Comment: Ah, no, you want 0 logins first, then logins descending, and *within a group with the same number of logins*, it is a date sort, descending.

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered data types, you may want to look at [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) from the collections module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you know that dictionaries are unordered and that you want to sort either the values, or the key-value pairs. The following examples sort the values.

Your comparison function already works, provided you fix the `loigns` typo in the last `if`:

```
>>> sorted(sample.itervalues(), cmp=compare))
[{'logins': 0, 'date_added': 150}, {'logins': 0, 'date_added': 100}, {'logins': 500, 'date_added': 400, 'date_used': 500}, {'logins': 500, 'date_added': 300, 'date_used': 400}, {'logins': 20, 'date_added': 200, 'date_used': 300}]
>>> pprint(_)
[{'date_added': 150, 'logins': 0},
 {'date_added': 100, 'logins': 0},
 {'date_added': 400, 'date_used': 500, 'logins': 500},
 {'date_added': 300, 'date_used': 400, 'logins': 500},
 {'date_added': 200, 'date_used': 300, 'logins': 20}]
```

However, you can use the following sort key too:

```
(not d['logins'], d['logins'], d['date_used'] if d['logins'] else d['date_added'])
```

This creates a tuple of `(has_logins, num_logins, date)` where the date picked is based on whether or not the user has logged in.

Use it as the `key` argument to the `sorted()` function, and reverse the sort, like this:

```
>>> key = lambda d: (not d['logins'], d['logins'], d['date_used'] if d['logins'] else d['date_added'])
>>> pprint(sorted(sample.itervalues(), key=key, reverse=True))
[{'date_added': 150, 'logins': 0},
 {'date_added': 100, 'logins': 0},
 {'date_added': 400, 'date_used': 500, 'logins': 500},
 {'date_added': 300, 'date_used': 400, 'logins': 500},
 {'date_added': 200, 'date_used': 300, 'logins': 20}]
```

If you needed the keys as well, use `dict.iteritems()` and update the key function to accept a `(k, d)` tuple:

```
>>> key = lambda (k, d): (not d['logins'], d['logins'], d['date_used'] if d['logins'] else d['date_added'])
>>> pprint(sorted(sample.iteritems(), key=key, reverse=True))
[('unused_account', {'date_added': 150, 'logins': 0}),
 ('unused_account2', {'date_added': 100, 'logins': 0}),
 ('power_user_2', {'date_added': 400, 'date_used': 500, 'logins': 500}),
 ('power_user', {'date_added': 300, 'date_used': 400, 'logins': 500}),
 ('regular_user', {'date_added': 200, 'date_used': 300, 'logins': 20})]
```

Comment: Thanks, I in fact needed the keys as well. Thanks for including that snippet.