# Python sort down & up in same dictionary

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

Team,

How to sort a dictionary up *and* down.

> `sorted(dictionary.keys(), reverse=True)` generates the 'FROM' result below:
>   and I'm looking for a result like 'TO:'.

```
NOW  (sort down)            GOAL: 
{
'5.000': 'Y2A7',            '5.000': 'Y2A7',
'4.000': 'Y2A5',            '4.000': 'Y2A5',
'3.000': 'Y2A3',            '3.000': 'Y2A3', 
'2.002': 'Y2A6', << .002    '2.000': 'Y2A2',        
'2.001': 'Y2A4', << .001    '2.001': 'Y2A4', << .001
'2.000': 'Y2A2',            '2.002': 'Y2A6', << .002
'1.000': 'Y2A1'             '1.000': 'Y2A1' 
}
```

Think of it as messages with replies that are sorted from new->old. 
The threaded messages should appear in old->new order, like this:

```
NOW:                GOAL: 
msg 5               msg 5
msg 4               msg 4
msg 3               msg 3
    msg 2.002       msg 2
    msg 2.001           msg 2.001
msg 2                   msg 2.002
msg 1               msg 1
```

It would not make sense if the message replies to 'msg 2' would be sorted new->old

Any idea how this could be done?

Comment: Use this , sorted(dictionary.keys(), reverse=True, key=float)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

learn to create a sort key which returns a tuple (see [Sort a dictionary with custom sorting function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31902857/sort-a-dictionary-with-custom-sorting-function)):

```
d = {
'5.000': 'Y2A7',
'4.000': 'Y2A5',
'3.000': 'Y2A3',
'2.002': 'Y2A6',
'2.001': 'Y2A4',
'2.000': 'Y2A2',
'1.000': 'Y2A1'
}

result = sorted(d , key = lambda x : (-int(float(x)),float(x)))

print(result)
```

the keys are now sorted properly:

```
['5.000', '4.000', '3.000', '2.000', '2.001', '2.002', '1.000']
```

`(-int(float(x)),float(x))` yields the opposite of integer value of the key (as float) as first tuple element, and as a tiebreaker, just the float value. So when the integer value is the same, the tiebreaker reverses the sort locally.

Now iterate using the sorted keys to get sorted dictionary data, or sort `d.items()` directly:

```
sorted(d.items(), key = lambda x : (-int(float(x[0])),float(x[0])))
```

Comment: Fantastic.. Such a simple 1-liner solution and it works great. Thank you!